# Numpy vectorize python for loop

Tags: numpy, vectorization

This is a code snippet using Keras library for creating models:

```
    for state, action, reward, next_state, done in minibatch:
        target = reward
        if not done:
            target = (reward + self.gamma *
                      np.amax(self.model.predict(next_state)[0]))
        target_f = self.model.predict(state)
        #print (target_f)
        target_f[0][action] = target
        self.model.fit(state, target_f, epochs=1, verbose=0)
```

I am trying to vectorize it. The only way I think to do is :
1. Create a numpy table with each row = (state, action, reward, next_state, done, target). So, there will be "mini-batch" number of rows.
2. Update target column based on other columns as (using masked arrays):

```
target[done==True] ==reward
target[done==False] == reward + self.gamma 
*np.amax(self.model.predict(next_state)[0])
```

3. Now update self.model.fit(state, target_f, epochs=1, verbose=0)

NB: state is 8-D, so state vector has 8 elements.

Despite hours of efforts, I am unable to code this properly. 
Is it possible to actually vectorize this piece of code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are very close! Assuming that `minibatch` is an `np.array`:

First find all the indices where `done` is true. Assuming `done` is index number 4.

```
minibatch_done=minibatch[np.where(minibatch[:,4]==True)]
minibatch_not_done=minibatch[np.where(minibatch[:,4]==False)]
```

Now we use this to update the `minibatch` matrix conditionally. Assuming index 2 is `reward` and index 3 is `next_state`

```
target = np.empty((minibatch.shape[0]))
n_done = minibatch_done.shape[0]
# First half (index 0...n_done)
target[:n_done] = minibatch_done[:,2]+self.gamma*np.amax(self.model.predict(minibatch_done[:,3]))
target[n_done:] = minibatch_not_done[:,2]
```

And there you have it :)

Edit: Fixed index error in target problems

Comment: Thanks.. But when updating model using model.fit(), the states and corresponding targets should be in a row. Here, does target preserve the order of state?

Comment: It does preserve the order of state. Just do `target.reshape((-1,1))` to make it a column vector

Comment: Thanks Andrew. Would you please also take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51068981/vectorized-update-numpy-array-using-another-numpy-array-elements-as-index

Comment: Hi Andrew, I found a problem. The target was only having the values of minibatch_not_done. I think the target is getting overwritten, might be a masked array on target will help.

Comment: target[np.where(minibatch[:,3]==True)]=minibatch_done[:,1]+1*(minibatch_done[:,2])
target[np.where(minibatch[:,3]==False)]=minibatch_not_done[:,1]

Comment: You are right, @SurabhiAmitChembra! Fixed it in the answer.

Comment: Thank you @Andreas, appreciate the help!