# Vectorized Update numpy array using another numpy array elements as index

Tags: python, numpy, vectorization

Let A,C and B be numpy arrays with the same number of rows.
I want to update 0th element of A[0], 2nd element of A[1] etc. That is, update B[i]th element of A[i] to C[i]

```
import numpy as np
A = np.array([[1,2,3],[3,4,5],[5,6,7],[0,8,9],[3,7,5]])
B = np.array([0,2,1,2,0])
C = np.array([8,9,6,5,4])
for i in range(5):
A[i, B[i]] = C[i]
print ("FOR", A)
A = np.array([[1,2,3],[3,4,5],[5,6,7],[0,8,9],[3,7,5]])
A[:,B[:]] = C[:]
print ("Vectorized, A", A)
```

Output:

```
FOR [[8 2 3]
[3 4 9]
[5 6 7]
[0 8 5]
[4 7 5]]
Vectorized, A [[4 6 5]
[4 6 5]
[4 6 5]
[4 6 5]
[4 6 5]]
```

The for loop and vectorization gave different results.
 I am unsure how to vectorize this for loop using Numpy.

Comment: `A[np.arange(A.shape[0]), B] = C`

Comment: @WarrenWeckesser This will also change the last row.

Comment: The description in the text makes it sound like the last row *should* be updated.  I assumed `range(4)` is a typographical error.

Comment: @WarrenWeckesser Yeah, that's what I assumed at first and hesitated to post an answer but still as I explained in my answer it's simply possible to do so.

Comment: Surabhi, shouldn't the last row of `C` be `[4, 7, 5]`?

Comment: @ Warren. Yes, you are right. It was a mistake, will edit the question. Last row should be [4,7,5]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason that your approach doesn't work is that you're passing the whole `B` as the column index and replace them with `C` instead you need to specify both row index and column index. Since you just want to change the first 4 rows you can simply use `np.arange(4)` to select the rows `B[:4]` the columns and `C[:4]` the replacement items.

```
In [26]: A[np.arange(4),B[:4]] = C[:4]

In [27]: A
Out[27]: 
array([[8, 2, 3],
       [3, 4, 9],
       [5, 6, 7],
       [0, 8, 5],
       [3, 7, 5]])
```

Note that if you wanna update the whole array, as mentioned in comments by @Warren you can use following approach:

```
A[np.arange(A.shape[0]), B] = C
```